# What would be the variance of a circulary complex normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

When $x$ is a zero mean random variable then, $\sum_{n=1}^N x_n x_n^T = N \sigma^2_x$ where the variance is $\sigma^2_x$. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution explains about the form of the distribution for complex normal distribution. 
I am looking at the circularly symmetric complex normal distribution, where real and imaginary part are completely uncorrelated.

I have a confusion because the denominator for the real case in the distribution has a 2 but for the complex that is not there. Does this mean that if $x$ is a complex valued random variable, then the variance becomes half i.e., $\sum_{n=1}^N x_n x_n^H = N \sigma^2_x/2$ where the variance is $\sigma^2_x/2$ because the variance gets equally distributed in the real and imaginary component? I have this doubt because when implementing, if I need to generate a complex noise of variance 1, I would be doing (in Matlab)

`noise = sqrt(1/2) * (randn(N,1) + 1j*randn(N,1))`

Since each component (real and imaginary) needs to have variance 1/2, such that their sum becomes 1.

$P_x = \frac{1}{\pi \sigma^2_x} \exp \bigg(\frac{-{(({x}))}^H (({x}))}{\sigma^2_x} \bigg)$

For real case, there would be a `2` in the denominator. But, for complex, there is no 2. 
So, the variance $\sigma^2$ is half mathematically. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that if xx is a complex valued random variable, then
>   the variance becomes half…

No.  The half disappears in the complex case because the integral over the complex doesn't need it.  [1] writes about this:

> Note the simpler form of [the density], essentially due to Gauss’s integral
>   operating more cleanly over the complex plane than the real line…

Regarding your sampling method, your understanding is correct.  You want the variance of the real projection and the variance of the complex projection to both be one half because variances add.  The total variance would then be one.

Assuming $E(x)$ is zero, which it is for a circularly-symmetric complex normal, then $E(x x^H)$ is the variance, and $E(x x^T)$ is the *pseudo-variance* for which there is no real equivalent.  The pseudo-variance is zero for a circularly-symmetric complex normal distribution

[1] Hankin, Robin KS. "The complex multivariate Gaussian distribution." The R Journal 7.1 (2015): 73-80.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am still unclear about the expression $\Sigma x_n x_n^H$ would be for the complex case. Can you also answer this part?

Comment: @RiaGeorge That's the variance.  $x x^T$ is the *pseudo-variance* for which there is no real equivalent.

Comment: I think I could not explain myself well in my comment. For the case of real valued $x$, we do agree that $\Sigma x_n x_n^T = N \sigma^2_x$. This is the ML estimator for the variance for zero mean real valued random variable. For complex case, what would be the ML estimator for the variance be ?would $\Sigma x_n x_n^H$ evaluate to the same expression as $N \sigma^2_x$ or $N \sigma^2_x/2$?.

Comment: @RiaGeorge $\sigma^2$ is defined to be $E(x^2)$ in the real case.  You are welcome to define $\sigma^2$ to be $E(x x^\ast)$ (or whatever you like) for the complex case.  In any case, this latter expression is the "variance".

Comment: $N$ are the total number of samples or n observations. In the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Non-degenerate_case the expression for variance is given by $\hat{Sigma} = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma x_n x_n^T$ (where $\mu=0$ in my case). Hence, I wrote $\Sigma x_n x_n^T = N\hat{Sigma} $ MY question is that for complex case, what would the term $\Sigma x_n x_n^*$ be?

Comment: $E(x x^H)$ *is the “variance”* — not $E(x x^T)$.  But anyway, this is just terminology.  You are welcome to use whatever names you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57266/discussion-between-neil-g-and-ria-george).